# Can not figure out the report of git blame

Tags: git

I am trying out `git blame` on a specific file. If I understand correctly it shows all modifications made to the file and by who.
But when I run the command the results do not appear in an orderly manner. I have to search the entries to figure out which was the last change by dates.
What is the order that the results are reported? How could I get the report according to the order of modification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git blame <filename>` shows, for each individual line in the file, the last commit to change that line.

To get a list of commits that touched a file, use `git log <filename>`, possibly with `-p` to also see the changes.

Comment: I thought that each commit is related to more than one files.I.e. the files that represent the specific snapshot.So `git log` showing that commits can not show history of a single file. So a commit is a snapshot of files but we can have the history of a single file? Do I make sense here?I am new in Git

Comment: @Cratylus If you give a filename to `git log`, it will simply ignore the commits in which the file wasn't changed. And with `-p`, it will filter the changes it shows, so that you only see what changed in that one file.
The whole history is still there, and each commit is associated with all its files; only the output is limited to the history of a single file.

Answer (score 3):

`git blame` "Annotates each line in the given file with information from the revision which last modified the line."  The output is ordered by the lines in the files.  Here is a typical output:

```
b62460a4 base.scm        (GoZoner 2011-01-11 17:44:21 -0800   1) ;-*- Mode: scheme -*-
b62460a4 base.scm        (GoZoner 2011-01-11 17:44:21 -0800   2) ;
b62460a4 base.scm        (GoZoner 2011-01-11 17:44:21 -0800   3) ; File:    base.scm
b62460a4 base.scm        (GoZoner 2011-01-11 17:44:21 -0800   4) ; Date:    Tue Jan 11 2011
...
528c5424 base.scm        (GoZoner 2012-04-21 10:01:14 -0700  26) ; ______________________________________________
b62460a4 base.scm        (GoZoner 2011-01-11 17:44:21 -0800  27) 
499ff1ef base.scm        (GoZoner 2010-10-21 22:08:30 -0700  28) (library (quirk base)
d1376b80 base.scm        (GoZoner 2011-01-01 16:31:00 -0800  29)   (export ignore identity always compose complem
6150ec79 base.scm        (GoZoner 2013-04-22 08:02:43 -0700  30)        iota choose choose-by split substitute de
9fc800e6 base.scm        (GoZoner 2010-10-28 07:36:01 -0700  31)        any? every? count index while until repea
499ff1ef base.scm        (GoZoner 2010-10-21 22:08:30 -0700  32)        member? associate
93933128 base.scm        (GoZoner 2010-10-22 01:03:43 -0700  33)        intersection union difference
3e3f47ee base.scm        (GoZoner 2010-11-20 15:59:38 -0800  34)        list-ref-at list-set-at list-ref-last lis
3e3f47ee base.scm        (GoZoner 2010-11-20 15:59:38 -0800  35)        vector-ref-at vector-index
5eae93ea base.scm        (GoZoner 2010-10-23 10:30:37 -0700  36)        symbol-append
```

You can see the: commit, filename, user, date, lineno, and contents for each line.

If you want something grouped by date, you have two options:

- `git log -- <filename>` shows the commits in reverse chronological
  order
- `git show <commit> -- <filename>` shows the changes to file
  for a given commit.